# I am getting unwanted loading of previous plot axis points to the next plot in PyQt5 matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, pyqt5

I am trying to update the plot after a new file is selected, but the new plot that is generated it has the points that are of previous plot on both X and Y axis, I don't want to those previous points, please anyone explain why this happens so and how to get rid of this. Images are shown here, previous plot is [image: plot 1]

after this I choose to select second file with different data to plot it, next plot is this image[image]

The code I am trying to build is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QFileDialog, QPushButton, QLabel, QGridLayout, QVBoxLayout, QLineEdit)

from Bio import SeqIO
from collections import Counter
from Bio.SeqUtils import molecular_weight
from Bio.SeqUtils import GC

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
       
        self.setWindowTitle("DNA Sequence Analysis - Prashik Lokhande")
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        
        my_label = QLabel("DNA Sequence Analysis from the FASTA Database, (FASTA databse can be found on NCBI website). Build by Prashik Lokhande")
        self.layout().addWidget(my_label)
  
        self.visualize()
        self.show()
        
        
    def visualize(self):
        container = QWidget()
        container.setLayout(QGridLayout())
        
        label_1 = QLabel("PLease Select FASTA file")
        
        button_1 = QPushButton("Select file", clicked = lambda: self.get_plot())
        gc_count_label = QLabel("GC Count = ")
        self.gc_count_field = QLabel("0")
        
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(plt.Figure(figsize=(10, 4)))
        
        container.layout().addWidget(label_1, 0,0)
        container.layout().addWidget(button_1, 1,0)
        container.layout().addWidget(gc_count_label, 2, 1)
        container.layout().addWidget(self.gc_count_field, 3, 1)
        container.layout().addWidget(self.canvas, 2, 0, 3, 1)
        
        self.layout().addWidget(container)
        
    
    def get_plot(self):
        filepath, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'select FASTA file')
        record = SeqIO.read(filepath,"fasta")
        
        dna = record.seq
        mrna = dna.transcribe()
        protein = mrna.translate()
        
        self.mol_weight = molecular_weight(dna)
        
        gc = GC(dna)
        self.gc_count_field.setText(str(gc))
        
        pr_freq = Counter(protein)
        
        self.ax = self.canvas.figure.subplots()
        
        self.ax.bar(pr_freq.keys(), pr_freq.values())
        self.ax.set_title("Amino Acid Contents in the sequence (X-axis Amino acids, Y-axis frequency)")
        
        

app = QApplication([])

mw = MainWindow()

app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you press the button, `self.ax = self.canvas.figure.subplots()` will create a new set of axes and add it at the (0,0) position in the grid of previously created subplots. Since all subplots are placed at the same position in the grid they all overlap. To get around this, you could just create one set of axes in `MainWindow.__init__`, and reuse this one in `MainWidon.get_plot`, i.e.

```
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        ....
        self.ax = self.canvas.figure.subplots()

    def get_plot(self):
        ....

        # clear previous plot
        self.ax.clear()
        self.ax.bar(pr_freq.keys(), pr_freq.values())

        ....
```

Comment: yes, this worked, thank you,  but with this I have got a issue that the plot doesn't get updated, to update it I need to stretch or contract the window using mouse cursor, so can you suggest how to work upon that..

Comment: You could try adding `self.canvas.draw_idle()` after `self.ax.bar(...)`.